# article with notitlepage still has the title page separately. why?

Tags: formatting

It seems strange from what I've read because the documentclass article should not generate a separate page for the title. For me, it does, though. Even if I add the option `notitlepage`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}
%%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{ngerman}
%\usepackage[ps2pdf,a4paper,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[a4paper,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[a4paper,%
    inner=3.5cm,%
    outer=3.5cm,%
    top=4cm,%
    bottom=4cm,%
    marginparwidth=2.5cm,%
    marginparsep=0.3cm,%
    includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle = {Semi-smooth Newton},%
    pdfsubject = {},%
    pdfauthor = {Albert Zeyer}%
}

\include{texdefs}

\begin{document}
\title{Semi-smooth Newton}
\author{Albert Zeyer}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\include{main}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Where main.tex contains the main content (starts with a `\section`) and texdefs.tex contains some `\newcommand` and other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found the problem. `\include` adds a new page. I have to use `\input` instead.

Comment: `\include` always does a page break.